# Сервер не на localhost

Tags: java, сервер, rmi

Как сделать так, чтобы сервер был виден user, который подключен к другой сети, но к общей глобальной? В одной локальной сервер я открываю на localhost. Пытался открыть сервер на ip http://myip.ru/ клиент не может подключиться к серверу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доступ к серверу из интернета можно предоставить путем проброса нужного порта на роутере с wan-интерфейса на ip-адрес:порт сервера в локальной сети. Плюс сервер должен принимать подключения не только на loopback-интерфейсе, но и на сетевой карте подключенной к lan.